# R: Using IDs from another table, replace these IDs in 2 columns in another table with the relevant data

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 tables and would like to use column C to extract the data of column D and replace the values in the other table columns, A and B, containing matching values with the relevant data of column D.

**Table 1:**

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dog |
| 2 | cat |
| 3 | mouse |
| 4 | lion |
| 5 | tiger |
| 12 | elephant |
| 7 | ant |
| 10 | rabbit |

**Table 2:**

| X | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 1 | 4 |
| 31 | 2 | 12 |
| 32 | 5 | 10 |

**Desired output:**

| X | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | dog | lion |
| 31 | cat | elephant |
| 32 | tiger | rabbit |

I tried using setkey and match but I am not sure if this is the correct way as I did not get the required output. Any help or suggestion appreciated please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `match`:

```r
df2[-1] <- df1$D[match(unlist(df2[-1]), df1$C)]

   X     A        B
1 30   dog     lion
2 31   cat elephant
3 32 tiger   rabbit
```

Comment: Hi Maël, thank you for your answer and help. Could you tell me if I have other columns in the output, how to get those pls? For example, if the desired output has an extra column relating to weight or food type. I used your answer on another set of data and these columns are coming up as NA and only columns X, A and B showing data

Comment: The `-1` is used to select the columns. You can change it to select only A and B: `df2[c("A", "B")]`

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df2 %>%
   mutate(across(A:B,  ~deframe(df1)[as.character(.x)]))
```

-output

```
 X     A        B
1 30   dog     lion
2 31   cat elephant
3 32 tiger   rabbit
```

Comment: Nice use of deframe() here!

Comment: as.character is here for safety, right?

Comment: @GuedesBF No, it is to match the names correctly.  Otherwise, it will just extract based on the numeric index which can be wrong.  In this case it may work as it is in a sequence